# Issue setting up Open vSwitch on GCE (DHCP client not working)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dhcp, bridge, openvswitch, google-cloud-networking

I am trying to simulate an on-premises solution on GCP.
I am not able to bridge with the GCE NIC and get DHCP working on that.

I have isolated the issue and also successfully tests the similar thing on a sandboxed Vagrant (VirtualBox) setup.

Both approaches are scripted and available on the following repos:
https://github.com/htssouza/ovs-gcp-issue

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP functionality for Compute Engine only provides and manages the IP address for the instance itself.  It does not function as a general purpose DHCP server for other clients running hosted inside the instance.